# Use sperate pool for sites with HHVM

Tags: nginx, php, hhvm

I am using HHVM 3.0.1(rel) with nginx over unix socket. I would like to setup pooling as in php-fpm and use different pools for different sites and allocate resources very accurately. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, no. It's in the backlog of things to add, or you could work on adding it yourself.

The current workaround is to have multiple instances of HHVM running on different ports and manually set up pools that way.

Comment: Actually the current workaround is the way to go. There are no plans to get pools into hhvm directly. https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/issues/1461